# Why does make_shared allocate same address in separate calls?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does this make_shared allocate the same memory address in two separate calls?

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} test_t;

void call_func()
{
    std::shared_ptr<test_t> tst = std::make_shared<test_t>();

    std::cout << "addr: " << tst << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    call_func();
    call_func();
}
```

Here it is online:
    http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffc92bc131009402

Comment: Most probably you're not aware of the scope of your variable!

Comment: The `new` gnomes doth declare it so!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Because it can.

`call_func()` creates a new `test_t` object in available memory and wraps it inside a `std::shared_ptr`.  The `test_t` object is destroyed when the `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope when `call_func()` exits.

So, when the first call to `call_func()` exits, the memory that it used has been freed and is available for re-use when the second call to `call_func()` is made.

This is normal behavior, nothing to worry about.